# How can I find the vertexes of a Polygon?

Tags: graphics3d

I made a polygon with the following vertexes :

```
p = {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 300}, {0, 300, 300}, {0, 300, 0}};(*Vertices of the polygon*)
myGraphics=Graphics3D[{Polygon[p]}, Boxed -> False, Lighting -> {Gray}];
```

How can I find the vertexes of `myGraphics`?

Comment: You mean you want to "see" the coordinates of the vertexes from the polygon `myGraphics`? If so, try `InputForm@myGraphics`.

Comment: Sorry, I need to nitpick this! It's vertices, not vertexes.

Comment: please remember to 
accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, 
[`by clicking the checkmark sign`](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)`

Comment: @Joren I thought so too but FWIW Wikipedia says vertexes is acceptable...

Comment: @Joren, both "vertices" and "vertexes" are acceptable (as with "indexes" and "indices"); "vertexes" discomfits me personally, but that's more of a stylistic than a grammatical complaint.

Comment: @Joren I started editing the post to change them to vertices, and in fact, changed most of them before I realized that my browser was not highlighting them in red. To me, reading "Vertexes" is like hearing chalk scratch on the board. However, it is a valid word and an equivalent of vertices... :(

Answer (score 14):

Try the following:

```
In[2]:= Cases[myGraphics, Polygon[pts_] -> pts, Infinity]
Out[2]= {{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 300}, {0, 300, 300}, {0, 300, 0}}}
```

If your Graphics3D object had many polygons you would get a list comprised of lists of the vertexes of all of them.

#### Update

In response to István Zachar's commentL: to confine the pattern to match only 3D polygons, use

```
Cases[myGraphics, Polygon[pts:{{_,_,_}..}] -> pts, Infinity]
```

Comment: Just a note: this would extract 2D polygons from `Epilog` (if present) too.

Comment: You might go as far as `Polygon[pts:{{_,_,_}..},___] ` to take into account any options such as `VertexColors` if present.

Answer (score 11):

A function to extract graphics primitives:

```
ClearAll[getVrtxCoords];
getVrtxCoords[plot_, prims : {___}] := Module[{pts, pts2,
   prms = Alternatives @@ prims,
vcoords = Cases[plot, GraphicsComplex[{coords___}, __] :> {coords}, {0, Infinity}]},
pts = Cases[plot, prms[points : {({_, _} | {_, _, _}) ..}, ___] :> points, {0, 
 Infinity}];
If[vcoords === {},
If[pts === {}, {}, First@pts],
If[(pts2 =  Cases[plot, prms[{points___}, ___] :> 
   ((First[vcoords][[#]]) & /@ {points}), {0, Infinity}]) == {}, {}, First@pts2]]]
```

Examples:

```
(* OP's example : *)
p = {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 300}, {0, 300, 300}, {0, 300, 0}};
myGraphics =  Graphics3D[{Polygon[p]}, Boxed -> False, Lighting -> {Gray}];
Grid[{{"image", "Points", "Lines", "Polygons"},
   Prepend[Column[N[getVrtxCoords[myGraphics, {#}]]] & /@ 
  {Point, Line, Polygon},  myGraphics]},  Spacings -> {1, 1}, Dividers -> All]
```

[image]

A `2D` example with `GraphicsComplex`:

```
 v = Table[15 {Cos[t], Sin[t]}, {t, 0, 4 Pi, 4 Pi/5}];
grphcs2 = Graphics[GraphicsComplex[v, {Red, Thick, Polygon[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}],
 Blue, Opacity[.7], Polygon[{{1, 2, 3}, {3, 4, 5}},
  VertexColors -> {{Yellow, Yellow, Yellow}, {Blue, Blue, Blue}}],
 Opacity[1], Dashed, Thickness[.02], Brown, Line[{1, 4, 2}],
 PointSize[Large], Red, Point[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}]}]];
Grid[{{"image", "Points", "Lines", "Polygons"},
  Prepend[Column[N[getVrtxCoords[grphcs2, {#}]]] & /@
    {Point, Line, Polygon}, grphcs2]},   Spacings -> {1, 1}, Dividers -> All]
```

[image]

A `3D` example:

```
v3 = PolyhedronData["Dodecahedron", "VertexCoordinates"];
Short[i = PolyhedronData["Dodecahedron", "FaceIndices"]];
dodec = Graphics3D[{Yellow, GraphicsComplex[v3, Polygon[i]]}, ImageSize -> 300];
modifieddodec =  Graphics3D[{Opacity[.8], EdgeForm[Opacity[.3]], 
 Polygon[#, VertexColors -> Table[Hue[RandomReal[]], {25}]] & /@ 
  getVrtxCoords[dodec, {Polygon}]}, Lighting -> "Neutral",  ImageSize -> 300];
Grid[{{"image", "reconstructed", "Points", "Lines", "Polygons"}, 
   {dodec, modifieddodec,  N@getVrtxCoords[dodec, {Point}], 
    N@getVrtxCoords[dodec, {Line}], 
    Short[N@getVrtxCoords[dodec, {Polygon}], 10]}}, Spacings -> {1, 1},
 Dividers -> All, Alignment -> {Center, Top}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 9):

Another version using pattern matching which can be quite useful for other purposes as well (other than in @m_goldberg's patent solution, all points will be returned in one list, the primitive structure will not be preserved):

```
Cases[myGraphics, {x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ, z_?NumericQ}, Infinity]
```

> ```
> {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 300}, {0, 300, 300}, {0, 300, 0}}
> ```

Why is that approach (esp. the pattern) useful? You can easily work on the coordinates and it works on several important `Graphics3D` primitives (`Point`, `Line`, `Polygon`,`Text`) out of the box regardless of the structure of your expression. Apart from the {x,y,z} tuples your expression is not changed.

```
myGraphics /. {x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ, z_?NumericQ} :> {x, 2 y-z, 3 z}
```

For multi-primitive syntax, `GraphicsComplex` etc. this approach works as well if you get a bit more fancy on the pattern side.

Comment: @Ajasja that wuz quick - thx :-)

Comment: Hehe, just drinking my morning coffee, and browsing the site. I did consider that it would be polite to wait, but in the end I said "meeh, the post won't go into community wiki because of one edit:)"

Comment: @Ajasja no worries, coffeedit away!