# How do I put an image on the complex plane?

Tags: image-processing, complex

I watched [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MWHMzgZ4VIk) and became interested in transforming an image. But I have no good idea on how to embed an image in the complex plane using *Mathematica*.

I have a method that seems to work, but there has to be a better way to do this. Can somebody point me in the right direction?

```
a = Reverse[ImageData[ImageApplay[Mean,img]]]

f[c_] := Module[{re, im, d1, d2},
   {d1, d2} = Dimensions[a];
   re = Round[Re[d2 c]];
   im = Round[Im[d1 c]];
   If[1 <= re <= d2 && 1 <= im <= d1, a[[im, re]], 1]
];

ListDensityPlot@Table[f[(y + x I)], {x, -1, 1.5, 0.02}, {y, -1, 1.5, 0.02}]
```

Comment: See http://shuisman.com/?p=1401#more-1401 and [this question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/16991/61)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`ImageForwardTransformation[]` is the function you want here. To give a concrete example, here's how an image might be transformed by the complex mapping $w=z^3$:

```
img = ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Mandrill"}];
imgc = ImageForwardTransformation[img, Through[{Re, Im}[(#[[1]] + I #[[2]])^3]] &,
                         Background -> 1,
                         DataRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}, PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}}]
```

[image: cubed mandrill]

To see the correspondence with the more usual complex mapping, we show the transformed image along with a suitably transformed Cartesian grid:

```
ParametricPlot[{Re[(x + I y)^3], Im[(x + I y)^3]}, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1},
               PlotStyle -> FaceForm[None], Prolog -> {Texture[imgc],
               Polygon[Scaled /@ {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}},
                       VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}]}]
```

[image: cubed mandrill with grid]

---

As an example of a nontrivial complex mapping, here is the conformal mapping of a square region to a disk:

```
img = ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Mandrill"}];
imgc = With[{ω = N[1/2 EllipticK[1/2], 25]},
            ImageForwardTransformation[img, 
                         With[{z = ω (#[[1]] + I #[[2]])},
                              Through[{Re, Im}[JacobiSC[z, 1/2] JacobiDN[z, 1/2]]]] &, 
                         Background -> 1, DataRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}, 
                         PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}]]
```

[image: mandrill on a disk]

Another nontrivial example of a complex mapping (the quincuncial projection) is demonstrated in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/24261) (though the procedure given there uses `ImageTransformation[]` instead).

Comment: Now Mandrill sad ;-(

Comment: @Yves, after getting stretched and warped a lot, who wouldn't? Lenna was lucky I didn't pick her for this experiment...