# Peirce's quincuncial projection

Tags: special-functions, geodesy, projection

The [Peirce quincuncial projection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peirce_quincuncial_projection) is the cartographic projection of a sphere onto a square.

In short, I would like to see it implemented in *Mathematica*.

Here is my code:

```
Clear[InversePeirceQuincunicalMapping]; 
InversePeirceQuincunicalMapping[x_Real, y_Real] := 
 Module[{cn, m = 1/2, th, phi},
        cn = JacobiCN[x 2 EllipticK[m] + I 2 y EllipticK[1 - m], m];
        {th, phi} = {2 ArcTan[Abs[cn]], Arg[cn]};
        {th, phi}]

zf[{th_, phi_}] := Cos[th]
xf[{th_, phi_}] := Sin[th] Cos[phi]
yf[{th_, phi_}] := Sin[th] Sin[phi]
```

The contours that correspond to the equation $\theta=\frac{\pi}{2}$, besides the expected tilted square, also includes the diagonal and anti-diagonal. This is not an artifact and can be [proven](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/375329).

[image: contour of inverse Peirce mapping]

These lines make me suspect that I am not doing the projection the right way. I would be glad to see a prototype implementation of it in *Mathematica*.

Thank you.

Comment: The implementation I did is for images. Would this be admissible? (I can jury-rig something that transforms a mesh, tho.)

Comment: Yes, completely. Additionally, there is a fun way to use this projection to build spherical panoramas, which is what I am ultimately after. [arXiv:1011.3189](http://arxiv.org/abs/1011.3189) and [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peirce_quincuncial_projection) provide examples.

Comment: I haven't tried turning my implementation into something for producing panoramas, but okay, I'll put in my take...

Comment: For more information on the cartographic applications of elliptic functions, see [this](http://utpjournals.metapress.com/content/t4p12p15220m/).

Answer (score 50, accepted):

(I had been meaning to write a blog entry about this myself, but since this question has come up, I suppose I'll just write about it here instead...)

In demonstrating how the [quincuncial projection](http://dx.doi.org/10.2307/2369491) works, consider first the following complex mapping:

```
With[{ω = N[EllipticK[1/2], 20]},
     ParametricPlot[{Re[InverseJacobiCN[Tan[φ/2] Exp[I θ], 1/2]],
                     Im[InverseJacobiCN[Tan[φ/2] Exp[I θ], 1/2]]},
                    {φ, 0, π}, {θ, -π, π}, Mesh -> Automatic,
                    MeshStyle -> {Orange, Green}, PlotPoints -> 75,
                    PlotRange -> {{0, 2 ω}, {-ω, ω}}]]
```

[image: Peirce's projection]

The components should be easily recognizable (e.g. the argument of the elliptic integral is a stereographic projection/Riemann sphere representation of a complex number).

The only fixed thing in applying the projection is the use of either the cosine amplitude function $\mathrm{cn}\left(u\mid \frac12\right)$ or its inverse; the choice of which stereographic projection to do is dependent on what coordinate convention you take for spherical coordinates.

For instance, if your convention is longitude/latitude (as with the output of `CountryData[]`), here's how one might implement the projection:

```
world = {{Switch[CountryData[#, "Continent"],
                 "Asia", Yellow, "Oceania", Green, "Europe", Pink,
                 "NorthAmerica", Red, "SouthAmerica", Orange, "Africa", GrayLevel[1/10],
                 "Antarctica", GrayLevel[9/10], _, Blue], 
          CountryData[#, {"FullPolygon", "Equirectangular"}]} & /@ 
          Append[CountryData[], "Antarctica"]} /.
          {θ_?NumericQ, φ_?NumericQ} :>
          Through[{Re, Im}[InverseJacobiCN[Cot[φ °/2 + π/4] Exp[I θ °], 1/2]]];

With[{ω = N[EllipticK[1/2], 20]}, 
 tile = Image[Graphics[Prepend[world,
                       {ColorData["Legacy", "PowderBlue"], Rectangle[{0, -ω}, {2 ω, ω}]}],
                       ImagePadding -> None, PlotRangePadding -> None],
              ImageResolution -> 300]]
```

[image: quincuncially-projected world map]

The only snag in this is that some post-processing is necessary if one wants to remove the polygons that are turned into "slivers" by the transformation, as can be seen when one tries to tile the image given above:

```
Graphics[{Texture[tile], 
          Polygon[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}, 
                  VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}, {0, 0}}], 
          Polygon[{{1, 0}, {2, 0}, {2, 1}, {1, 1}}, 
                  VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{0, 1}, {0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}}], 
          Polygon[{{0, 1}, {1, 1}, {1, 2}, {0, 2}}, 
                  VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{0, 1}, {0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}}], 
          Polygon[{{1, 1}, {2, 1}, {2, 2}, {1, 2}}, 
                  VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}, {0, 0}}]}]
```

[image: A Peirce tiling]

(You can do the sliver removal yourself, if you want it.)

---

If, like me, you prefer the longitude/colatitude convention, the stereographic projection proceeds a bit differently. For this example, I'll transform an image instead of transforming polygons. `ImageTransformation[]` does a nice job for this route:

```
earthGrid = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zzox0.png"];
With[{ω = N[EllipticK[1/2], 20]},
     eg = ImageTransformation[earthGrid, 
          With[{w = JacobiCN[#[[1]] + I #[[2]], 1/2]}, {Arg[w], 2 ArcCot[Abs[w]]}] &, 
          DataRange -> {{-π, π}, {0, π}}, Padding -> 1., PlotRange -> {{0, 2 ω}, {-ω, ω}}]]
```

[image: quincuncially-projected image]

Using code similar to the one given above, we can see the tiling for this as well:
[image: Peirce tiled image]

For image transformation purposes, however, I have found the execution of the built-in `JacobiCN[]` for complex arguments to be a bit slow, so I wrote my own implementation of a function that can replace `JacobiCN[z, 1/2]`:

```
SetAttributes[cnhalf, Listable];
cnhalf[z_?NumericQ] := Block[{nz = N[z], k, zs},
       k = Max[0, Ceiling[Log2[4 Abs[nz]]]];
       zs = (nz 2^-k)^2;
       Nest[With[{cs = #^2}, -(((cs + 2) cs - 1)/((cs - 2) cs - 1))] &,
            (1 - zs/4 (1 + zs/30 (1 + zs/8)))/(1 + zs/4 (1 - zs/30 (1 - zs/8))), k]]
```

which works quite nicely. (Exercise: try to recognize the formulae I used.)

Using, for instance, the [ETOPO1 global relief](http://www.ngdc.noaa.gov/mgg/global/),

```
etopo1 = Import["http://www.ngdc.noaa.gov/mgg/image/color_etopo1_ice_low.jpg"];
```

we finally present the other way to demonstrate the quincuncial projection:

```
With[{ω = N[EllipticK[1/2], 20]},
     etp = ImageTransformation[etopo1, 
           With[{w = cnhalf[#[[1]] + I #[[2]]]}, {Arg[w], 2 ArcCot[Abs[w]]}] &, 
           DataRange -> {{-π, π}, {0, π}}, Padding -> 1.,
           PlotRange -> {{0, 2 ω}, {-ω, ω}}]];

Graphics[{Texture[etp], 
         Polygon[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}, 
                 VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{1, 1}, {0, 1}, {0, 0}, {1, 0}}], 
         Polygon[{{1, 0}, {3/2, 0}, {3/2, 1/2}, {1, 1/2}}, 
                 VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{0, 0}, {1/2, 0}, {1/2, 1/2}, {0, 1/2}}],
         Polygon[{{1/2, -1/2}, {1, -1/2}, {1, 0}, {1/2, 0}}, 
                 VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{1/2, 1/2}, {1, 1/2}, {1, 1}, {1/2, 1}}],
         Polygon[{{1, -1/2}, {3/2, -1/2}, {3/2, 0}, {1, 0}},
                 VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{1, 1/2}, {1/2, 1/2}, {1/2, 0}, {1, 0}}]}]
```

[image: Another Peirce projection]

(I had previously posted this image in chat. Now you know where it came from. ;))

---

For an out-of-this-world bonus, here's another image that I have quincuncially projected:

[image: http://www.jpl.nasa.gov/spaceimages/details.php?id=PIA15482]

Can you guess the original equirectangular image I made this from?

Comment: +1 Want to know something about  cartographic projections long ago.

Comment: http://www.eugeneparnell.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/Orlando-Ferguson-flat-earth-map.jpg

Comment: @bel, "God plays roulette with the Earth"?

Comment: +1 for linking to a paper from 1879. I'd give more, but there are limits to this sort of thing. :)

Comment: @rcollyer, we should then be impressed that Peirce imagined all this without having *Mathematica* on his hands. :)

Comment: I am continuously impressed by the imaginations of those who developed stuff before computers. My adv. calc teacher had us draw 3D surfaces by hand, and I can't overstate its usefulness in being able to visualize functions to this day, not that I draw them by hand anymore ... :)

Comment: J.M., I just edited another one of your answers to replace "postprocessing" with "post-processing" as the former was not appearing in [a search](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/124077/121) for the latter.  The hyphenated form appears to be far more common; do you have strong preference for the other or may I change it?

Comment: @Mr. Wizard, no problem; if, as you say, it makes searching easier, then sure. :)

Comment: @J.M.'sdiscontentment cosmic bg?

Answer (score 16):

Just an update. This is now built in in WL:

```
GeoProjectionData["PeirceQuincuncial"]
```

> {"PeirceQuincuncial", {"Centering" -> {90, -90}, 
>         "GridOrigin" -> {0, 0}, "ReferenceModel" -> 1}}

```
GeoGraphics["World", 
GeoProjection -> "PeirceQuincuncial", 
 GeoBackground -> "ReliefMap"]
```

[image]

Comment: That's neat! Since when was it incorporated?

Comment: @J.M. Very recently I think.

Comment: @VitaliyKaurov Wondering if you can extract the projection as a function for use in `ImageTransformation`?