# Number of divisors visualized with the QPochhammer function, how to improve performance of code?

Tags: performance-tuning, visualization, special-functions, number-theory

I have this code that is originally Jeffrey Stopple's code for the Riemann zeta function in the complex plane. Because I discovered yesterday that the number of divisors can be generated with the $q$-Pochhammer symbol (`QPochhammer`), and since *Mathematica* shows a plot of `QPochhammer`, I thought that plotting it would be fun.

Here is the code that needs improvement:

```
Show[Graphics[RasterArray[
   Table[Hue[Mod[3 Pi/2 + 
        Arg[Sum[(s + I t)^(n - 1)*(QPochhammer[(s + I t)^(n + 1), (s + I t)]/
             QPochhammer[(s + I t)^(n), (s + I t)]), {n, 1, 100}]], 
       2 Pi]/(2 Pi)], {t, -1.1, 1.1, .05}, {s, -1.1, 1.1, .05}]]], 
 AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

And the code for the [number of divisors](https://oeis.org/A000005):

```
CoefficientList[
 Series[Sum[
   x^(n - 1)*(QPochhammer[x^(n + 1), x]/QPochhammer[x^(n), x]), {n, 1,
     104}], {x, 0, 103}], x] (*_ Mats Granvik_,Jan 03 2015*)

1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 4, 2, 4, 3, 4, 2, 6, 2, 4, 4, 5, 2, 6, 2, 6, 4, 4, 2, 8, 3, 4, 4,
6, 2, 8, 2, 6, 4, 4, 4, 9, 2, 4, 4, 8, 2, 8, 2, 6, 6, 4, 2, 10, 3, 6, 4, 6, 2, 8,
4, 8, 4, 4, 2, 12, 2, 4, 6, 7, 4, 8, 2, 6, 4, 8, 2,...
```

The plot from the first program that I would like to improve:

[image: Divisors from QPochhammer]

Already if someone could post a plot with higher resolution, I would be glad. My computer is rather old.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It looks like you want to plot the phase-only information of a complex function. Using the following helper functions for plotting the phase-only information complex functions:

```
hue = Compile[{{z, _Complex}}, {Mod[3 π/2 + Arg[z], 
      2 π]/(2 π), 1, If[Abs[z] > 10^-3, 1, 0]}, 
   CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}];
ComplexPlotC[f_, {x0_, x1_, δx_}, {y0_, y1_, δy_}] := 
  Image[hue[
     f[Outer[Complex, Range[x0, x1, δx], 
       Range[y1, y0, -δy]]]]\[Transpose], ColorSpace -> Hue, 
   Magnification -> 1];
CCompileC[expr_] := 
  Compile[{{z, _Complex}}, Evaluate[expr], CompilationTarget -> "C", 
   RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}];
```

You can then compile your function and plot it (I'll only sum 10 terms, rather than 100, as using 100 would take quite a long time):

```
func = CCompileC[
   If[Abs[z] >= 0.999, 0, 
    Sum[z^(n - 1)*(QPochhammer[z^(n + 1), z]/
        QPochhammer[z^(n), z]), {n, 1, 10}]]];
ComplexPlotC[func, {-1 + 10^-6 RandomReal[], 1, 
  0.003}, {-1 + 10^-6 RandomReal[], 1, 0.003}]
```

which gives the following:

[image]

Here is a 100-term sum picture (open in separate tab to see slightly larger picture):

[image]

Comment: damned: you scooped my 'brute force' solution by 2 minutes :-)

Comment: ah… but you stop at n=10?

Comment: @chris: Oops, good point, I changed it to 10 and totally forgot about it! Will edit. Ugh, now it's going to be *really* slow...

Comment: well that's why it was taking sooo long on 40 cores :-)

Comment: Your plot is really nice! I like it. Thanks.

Comment: @MatsGranvik: It's also slightly wrong, as the sum only goes up to 10, rather than 100.

Comment: @DumpsterDoofus It does not matter. Your coding skills are amazing. I like the image anyways.

Comment: @MatsGranvik: The helper functions I used are actually something I wrote a long time ago, and only needed a slight modification. I'll post the 40-term sum picture when I get the parallelization to work correctly.

Comment: its got more funny loops...

Comment: @chris: A pic with 2.5 times as many loops will hopefully finish up tonight...

Comment: Since `QPochhammer` is not compilable, you're probably better off not to compile `func`. `hue`, of course, can still freely be compiled.

Comment: @OleksandrR.: Weird, it never gave any "proceeding with uncompiled evaluation" warnings when I tested the function inside the unit circle. It *did* give "proceeding with uncompiled evaluation" warnings when $|z|>1$, which is why I added the `If` condition.

Answer (score 12):

As this is a [special-functions](/questions/tagged/special-functions) question, I feel justified in using a bit of heavy artillery. Here goes nothing...

In effect, what the OP seems to want to do is to evaluate

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(q^{n+1};q)_\infty}{(q^n;q)_\infty} q^{n-1}$$

(where $(a;q)_n$ is the [$q$-Pochhammer symbol](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/q-PochhammerSymbol.html)) by approximating it with its partial sums. However, there is a more streamlined expression for this function.

Using, for instance, formula 12 in the MathWorld page I linked to, we have

$$\begin{align*}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(q^{n+1};q)_\infty}{(q^n;q)_\infty} q^{n-1}&=\frac{(q^2;q)_\infty}{(q;q)_\infty}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\frac{(q;q)_\infty}{(q^{n+1};q)_\infty}}{\frac{(q^2;q)_\infty}{(q^{n+2};q)_\infty}} q^n\\&=\frac1{(q;q)_1}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(q;q)_n}{(q^2;q)_n} q^n\\&=\frac1{1-q}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(q;q)_n (q;q)_n}{(q^2;q)_n}\frac{q^n}{(q;q)_n}\end{align*}$$

and the infinite sum can now be recognized as the [$q$-hypergeometric function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/q-HypergeometricFunction.html) $$\frac1{1-q}\,{}_2\phi_1\left({{q,q}\atop{q^2}}\mid q,q\right)$$

or in *Mathematica* syntax, `QHypergeometricPFQ[{q, q}, {q^2}, q, q]/(1 - q)`.

Another expression is derived by noting that

$$\frac{(q;q)_n}{(q^2;q)_n}=\frac{1-q}{1-q^{n+1}}$$

Using this identity instead in the derivation above yields

$$\begin{align*}\frac1{1-q}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(q;q)_n}{(q^2;q)_n} q^n&=\frac1{q}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{q^n}{1-q^n}\end{align*}$$

i.e., a [Lambert series](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LambertSeries.html), which is expressible in terms of the [$q$-digamma function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/q-PolygammaFunction.html) (compare the definitions)

$$\frac{\psi_q(1)+\log(1-q)}{q\log q}$$

or `(QPolyGamma[1, q] + Log[1 - q])/(q Log[q])` in *Mathematica* syntax.

We now have two alternative expressions to choose from. The $q$-digamma function is faster to evaluate (at least in the tests I did), but the $q$-hypergeometric expression does not have the removable singularity at the origin.

If we are to use the $q$-digamma function expression, then, this precludes us from an `Image[]`-based approach such as the one in the OP and the other answer. We could use `DensityPlot[]` (since it does not visibly complain about singularities) with an appropriate `RegionFunction` setting, but a better way would be to use another classical technique, this time from [Schwarz and Christoffel](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Schwarz-ChristoffelMapping.html).

To be precise, what I'll do here is to use the conformal map from the unit square to the unit disk within `DensityPlot[]` and then perform an `ImageForwardTransformation[]` (like in the one done [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/24144)) to finally obtain the image on the unit disk. As mentioned in that other answer, the appropriate mapping function is `JacobiSN[z, 1/2] JacobiDC[z, 1/2]`. The built-in Jacobi elliptic functions are a bit slow for image transformation purposes, so I have written a compiled function that evaluates this mapping for complex arguments:

```
sdc = With[{c1 = 1./2678, c2 = 1101., c3 = 110.2, c4 = 5677./60, 
            c5 = 1577., c6 = 1479., c7 = 21739./60, d1 = 1./338, d2 = 51., 
            d3 = 1./15, d4 = 1709., d5 = 262.25, d6 = 287., d7 = 0.2, 
            d8 = 1591./3, d9 = 102.75},
           Compile[{{z, _Complex}}, Module[{dc, k, s, zs, zs2},
                    k = If[z == 0., 0, Max[0, Ceiling[Log2[4. Abs[z]]]]];
                    zs = z/(2^k); zs2 = (zs/2)^2;
                    {s, dc} = {(zs (1. - c1 zs2 (c2 + zs2 (c3 - c4 zs2))))/
                               (1. + c1 zs2 (c5 - zs2 (c6 - c7 zs2))),
                               (1. + d1 zs2 (d2 + d3 zs2 (d4 + d5 zs2)))/
                               (1. - d1 zs2 (d6 + d7 zs2 (d8 + d9 zs2)))};
                    Do[{s, dc} = {(2. s dc)/(1. + s^2 dc^2),
                                  (dc^2 - 0.5 s^2)/(1. - s^2 dc^2)}, {k}];
                    s dc], RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}]]
```

We now generate the image in two stages. First, here's the "raw" `DensityPlot[]`:

```
With[{ω = N[3 Beta[5/4, 5/4]/2], ε = 1/100},
     sqrimg = DensityPlot[With[{q = sdc[ω (x + I y)]}, 
                               Arg[(QPolyGamma[1, q] + Log[1 - q])/(q Log[q])]],
                          {x, -1 + ε, 1 - ε}, {y, -1 + ε, 1 - ε}, 
                          ColorFunction -> (Hue[Mod[#/(2 π) + 3/4, 1]] &), 
                          ColorFunctionScaling -> False, Frame -> None,
                          ImageSize -> Large, MaxRecursion -> 1,
                          PlotPoints -> 95, PlotRangePadding -> None]]
```

[image: distorted density plot of the Lambert series]

Some features should already be recognizable in this distorted image. Now, undo the Schwarz-Christoffel distortion like so:

```
With[{ω = N[3 Beta[5/4, 5/4]/2]}, 
     ImageForwardTransformation[sqrimg, With[{z = ω (#[[1]] + I #[[2]])},
                                Through[{Re, Im}[sdc[z]]]] &, Background -> 1.,
                                DataRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}]]
```

[image: The final image. :D]

Beautiful. If need be, you can always increase the setting for `PlotPoints` and `MaxRecursion`, but the picture already looks reasonably good to me. (Note that the jittery portion near $q=1$ in the other images posted is completely absent.)

Comment: (A similar technique was used to render my current Gravatar, with the Rogers-Ramanujan continued fraction as the function being plotted.)

Comment: These functions are not so familiar to me although I used them in my question, but your answer appears to be pretty rigourous.

Comment: I try my best when it comes to dealing with special functions. :)