# Refining a density plot of the Eisenstein series argument

Tags: plotting, special-functions

Thanks to amazing code from "Guess who it is" here: [Eisenstein Series in Mathematica?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/89430/eisenstein-series-in-mathematica) I'm able to make some nice plots using Eisenstein Series. What I'd like is a color plot of the argument of certain combinations of Eisenstein Series. What I have below, using `DensityPlot`, is nice, but what I was hoping for was something that emphasized more where the lines of constant argument are. Perhaps instead of a continuous variable for the angle, there is some way to partition the angles into 50 or so bins?  Maybe that would show a little clearer where the lines of constant argument are.

The code I have so far is:

```
SetAttributes[EisensteinE, Listable];

EisensteinE[2, t_, s_] := 
  With[{q3 = EllipticTheta[3, 0, Exp[I*Pi*(t + I*s)]]^2}, 
    6/Pi EllipticE[InverseEllipticNomeQ[Exp[I*Pi*(t + I*s)]]] q3 - 
     q3^2 - EllipticTheta[4, 0, Exp[I*Pi*(t + I*s)]]^4]

EisensteinE[4, t_, s_] := 
  (EllipticTheta[2, 0, Exp[I*Pi*(t + I*s)]]^8 + 
   EllipticTheta[3, 0, Exp[I*Pi*(t + I*s)]]^8 + 
   EllipticTheta[4, 0, Exp[I*Pi*(t + I*s)]]^8)/2

K[i_, j_] = ((EisensteinE[2, i, j])^2) - EisensteinE[4, i, j];

DensityPlot[Arg[K[i, j]/144], {i, -1/2, 1/2}, {j, 0, 3}, 
  ColorFunction -> Hue, PlotLegends -> Automatic, ImageSize -> 300]
```

If my idea above of discretizing the angles is lousy, is there a more convenient way to achieve this? Also, any thoughts on why portions of the plot are simply white, as opposed to one of the colors labeling an angle?

Comment: "lines of constant argument" - then you probably want the setting `MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}` and an appropriate setting for `Mesh`. Now a little technical note: `InverseEllipticNomeQ[Exp[I π τ]] == ModularLambda[τ]`.

Comment: @J. M.  Was precisely what I was looking for thanks!  I think the numerics break down for imaginary part of tau outside of 1/2<6, but within that region it looks perfect.