# High Precision Plots of Eisenstein Series

Tags: plotting, numerics, special-functions

When plotting the Eisenstein Series (great information here [Eisenstein Series in Mathematica?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/89430/eisenstein-series-in-mathematica)) you observe highly non-trivial branch cut behavior close to the real axis.  This makes the numerics break down, and you either get "blank spots" or incorrect plots.

Something very similar was dealt with here [Derivative of the Dedekind eta function fails to compute with errors I don't understand](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/99531/derivative-of-the-dedekind-eta-function-fails-to-compute-with-errors-i-dont-und).

About half-way down that thread, there is a fabulous answer suggesting the use of `Rationalize` to produce a much cleaner, more accurate plot.  I'm trying to apply that same procedure to plot a slightly different (quasi-) modular function.

Simply put, I'm trying to plot `Arg[K2]` where `K2` is defined in my code:

```
E22[z_] = 
  1 - 24*Sum[(n*Exp[2*Pi*I*(z)*n])/(1 - Exp[2*Pi*I*(z)*n]), {n, 1, 
      300}];
EisensteinE2[4, 
   z_] := (EllipticTheta[2, 0, Exp[I*Pi*(z)]]^8 + 
     EllipticTheta[3, 0, Exp[I*Pi*(z)]]^8 + 
     EllipticTheta[4, 0, Exp[I*Pi*(z)]]^8)/2;
K2[z_] = (((E22[z])^2) - EisensteinE2[4, z])/144;
Block[{f}, 
  f[z_?NumericQ] := 
   Block[{res}, res = Arg[N@Quiet@N[K2[z][Rationalize[z, 0]], 6]]];
  res /; NumericQ[res]];
ContourPlot[f[x + I y], {x, -.5, .5}, {y, 0.1, .5}, Contours -> 50, 
 ImageSize -> Full, AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

Unfortunately, this simply produces a blank plot.  I think I'm either applying the syntax of the suggested procedure in the answer above incorrectly, or there's something I don't understand about the use of `Rationalize` in my context.  Can anyone see where I'm screwing up here?

Comment: Your `Block` gets thrown away. Do you want `ContourPlot[Re@K2[x + I y], {x, -.5, .5}, {y, 0.1, .5}, 
 ImageSize -> Full, AspectRatio -> Automatic]`, or `ContourPlot[Im@K2[x + I y], {x, -.5, .5}, {y, 0.1, .5}, 
 ImageSize -> Full, AspectRatio -> Automatic]`?

Comment: Formatting tip: Select your code block and click the `{}` button in the toolbar (fifth from left, between the quote marks and the image button).

Comment: That was exactly what I was after, except with `Arg` replacing `Re` or `Im`, thanks!!  So I was somehow by-passing the `Block`?