# Custom color function in `ListContourPlot`?

Tags: plotting, graphics, visualization

I have a resource-consuming function of a complex variable, and I would like to make a contour plot of it with contours level curves of the modulus and the color coding the phase. If I just use `ContourPlot` it takes forever to draw it. `ListContourPlot` does it in reasonable time and I can regulate the number of sample points conveniently, but I could not figure out from [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ColorFunction.html) how to access the needed arguments for the color function: only "$f$ contour levels" is mentioned as available arguments. With the list of triples like `{x,y,Abs[f[x+I y]]}` I just need access to `Arg[f[x+I y]]` but I cannot figure out how to do it.

**Followup**

By request of [Kuba](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/5478/kuba) I am supplying (sort of) a minimal example, produced with

```
ListContourPlot[
 Flatten[
  Table[
   With[{q=r E^(I a)},
    {r Cos[a],
     r Sin[a],
     Log[Abs[QHypergeometricPFQ[{2,2q},{4q^2},q,-q^2 (1+2q)/(2(1-3q^2))]]]
    }
   ]
   ,{r,.01,.99,.005}
   ,{a,-\[Pi],\[Pi],\[Pi]/180}
  ]
  ,1
 ]
]
```

which results in

[image]

This differs essentially from the "real" case in several respects - e. g. I have actually a more complicated combination of these functions, and moreover I use iterative transformations to squeeze the values of the argument into the convergence region, filling the blind spots in the plot above.

Still it I believe suffices to reproduce what I need. I need the shading according to

```
Arg[QHypergeometricPFQ[{2,2q},{4q^2},q,-q^2 (1+2q)/(2(1-3q^2))]]
```

with `q` as above.

Comment: So you need colors which regions don't match contours? I'd go with your plot with `ContourShading->None` and `Show` it with `ListContourPlot` of `Arg[f[x+I y]`. You would already have an example but there is no minimal example to work with.

Comment: @Kuba Excellent suggestion, I think you may make this an answer. It is a hack but it gives what I want. More precisely I used `ListDensityPlot` with rainbow colors for the argument and then overlayed it with my `ListContourPlot` with no shading, and it's quite good.

Comment: Concerning minimal example - I wish I could supply it but cannot really figure out what to use. The whole point is that I need an involved function which cannot work with just `ContourPlot`s, and I don't know how to "minimize" it. Mine is a complicated combination of `QHypergeometricPFQ`s which is moreover transformed so as to access values of the argument where the builtin function does not converge.

Comment: A minimal example here is whatever C->C function and the domain limits. Expressed as e.g: `Table[Sin[x + I y], {x,0,1,.1},{y,0,1,.1}]` or something similar.

Comment: related: [7275](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7275/5478)

Comment: @Kuba Yes this seems closely related. So you suggest just to go levels down and directly use `Graphics`?

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/89673)?

Comment: @J.M. Yes thanks I was aware of it - however `DensityPlot` either produces similar blind spots as in my example here or needs hours of straining my processor to the full. This is why I had problems choosing a sufficiently illustrative example: if you look at the last argument of my function, it occasionally becomes huge when $q$ is inside the unit disc, so I am using various Heine transformations to trade for equivalent expressions with that last argument small.

Comment: Of course if I could transform this into something involving polygammas that would be great, but I don't know how to do it in my case. The thing you linked to involves logarithmic derivatives of some infinite products; in my case I have no idea whether any infinite products can be related.

Comment: "if I could transform this into something involving polygammas that would be great, but I don't know how to do it in my case." - prolly a good MO question, assuming there are $q$-experts there. As for the gaps in plotting the logarithm of the magnitude: have you tried adding `PlotRange -> All`? The phase is bounded, OTOH, so gaps apart from the cut on the negative real axis shouldn't pop up.

Comment: @J.M. I think there is a problem with intrinsics - I've checked, Mathematica just leaves the function unevaluated at some $q$s of interest. You are right, maybe I will make this a separate question.

Comment: As I recall, they only implemented `QHypergeometricPFQ[plist, qlist, q, z]` for $|q|, |z|<1$, so you will definitely need to use continuation identities if your arguments are off the unit disk.

Comment: @J.M. Exactly. My $|q|$ is inside, but $z$ has $2(1-3q^2)$ in the denominator. I wrote a subroutine to replace $z$ with $q^nz$ and tried to avoid recursive self-calls as much as possible, but it is still quite slow at times, and I am not sufficiently experienced with profiling to optimize it.