# Generating an Airy disk on a plane

Tags: plotting, graphics, graphics3d

I wish to generate a surface intensity plot of an Airy disk (or perhaps a two-dimensional Gaussian approximation to an Airy disk) on an (x, y)-plane at a specified coordinate.  The hope is to have something like this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Airy-3d.svg with solid surface coloration.  I am OK with a decent mesh approximation of a representative curve.

Is there a built in method of generating these sorts of intensity plots and treating them like Graphics3D objects that can be translated and placed as desired?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`RevolutionPlot3D` is a good tool for handling this question. The Airy function is given by

```
airy[r_?NumericQ, β_?NumericQ] := ((1 - E^(-(2/β^2))) BesselJ[1, (2 π r)/β]^2)/(π r^2 β^2)
```

Because 3D plotting is much slower, before proceeding to 3D, I recommend making a 2D plot to check that the parameter β has been chosen to give a good looking curve.

```
Plot[airy[r, 1.], {r, 0, 1.5}, AspectRatio -> Automatic, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: 2Dplot.png]

Because the revolution will be made about the z-axis, the arguments from the 2D plot can be transferred directly. To get the right look, it is necessary to adjust some the display options away from their default values.

```
plot = RevolutionPlot3D[airy[r, 1.], {r, 0, 1.5},
  Boxed -> False,
  BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1},
  Axes -> None,
  PlotRange -> All,
  Mesh -> 20,
  PlotPoints -> 100,
  Lighting -> {{"Ambient", White}}]
```

[image: 3Dplot.png]

A fine witches hat for Halloween.

To extract the polygons used to draw the `RevolutionPlot3D`, you can use kguler's function `getVrtxCoords` from [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/14039/3066). Here is what you will get

```
polygons = Polygon@getVrtxCoords[plot, {Polygon}];
Graphics3D[polygons]
```

[image: polygons.png]

Answer (score 7):

The plot referenced can be done with `Plot3D`. I grabbed the intensity profile from the [wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airy_disk)

```
{x0,y0}={0,0};
s[x_,y_]:=Sqrt[(x-x0)^2 + (y-y0)^2]
Plot3D[(2 BesselJ[1, s[x,y]]/s[x,y])^2,
  {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, PlotRange -> All,
  ColorFunction -> "BlueGreenYellow"]
```

[image: Airy disk]

I wasn't sure about what you meant by translating and placing, so you may have to redefine s[x,y] according its definition

```
k a Sin[θ] == s[x,y,z]
```