# Adding and summing overlapping Airy (or Gaussian) disks on a plane

Tags: plotting, graphics, graphics3d

In a previous question of mine, I asked how one might draw an Airy disk on a plane: [Generating an Airy disk on a plane](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/34407/generating-an-airy-disk-on-a-plane), and recieved some impressive answers from the users Timothy Wofford and m_goldberg

Might it be possible to have a 2D plane in the contexts of a Graphics3D environment, and generate an Airy disk wherever one clicks (a simpler 2D Gaussian curve would also be just fine)?  Or, perhaps more simply, to generate such disks at a specified set of two-dimensional coordiantes?  The hope is that this can be done s.t. overlapping sections of one or more curves can be summed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most important questions are:

- what do you need it for and what precission you are after?
- Is the *field* od peaks going to be *dense*?
- Airy function is disappearing very fast so maybe it's not important to keep track of the area outside the second minimum and approximation with `0` there is sufficient?

You can answer those questions and adjust the following code as you need. Here it is the straightforward implementation so it can be a little bit slow while adding points.

[Model](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/34409/5478) by [Timothy Wofford](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/9391/timothy-wofford):

```
airy2[{x_, y_}, {x0_, y0_}] := With[{s = Sqrt[(x - x0)^2 + (y - y0)^2]},
                                    (2 BesselJ[1, s]/s)^2]


With[{ran = 15},
 With[{opt = {ImageSize -> 300},  
       Gopt = {BaseStyle -> PointSize@.02, GridLines -> Automatic, Frame -> True,
               PlotRange -> ran},
       Popt = {Evaluated -> True, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", PlotPoints -> 20,  
               PlotRange -> {{-ran, ran}, {-ran, ran}, All}}
      },
  DynamicModule[{pkt = {{0, 0}}},
   Row[{
        ClickPane[Graphics[Dynamic@Point[pkt], opt, Gopt], AppendTo[pkt, #] &]
        ,
        Dynamic @ Plot3D[Plus @@ (airy2[{x, y}, #] & /@ pkt),
                         {x, -ran, ran}, {y, -ran, ran}, opt, Popt]

      }]
   ]
 ]]
```

[image]

Comment: This is just for a visualization application for a couple of points, and the field of points is not going to be very dense.  So this is pretty much precisely what I was looking for.  You make a good point that we should be able to zero-out the ring around the base of the Airy function curve without much effect.

Comment: Out of curiousity though, what is the precision here?  Can it be turned down to achieve a speedup?