# Creation of a test image with 2d circular shaped objects having Gaussian brightness distribution profile

Tags: image-processing

I want to create a test image which consists of 2d circular shaped objects each having a Gaussian brightness distribution profile.

To make it simple objects should be the same.

I then put the objects at random positions.

In the resulting composed image I would like to prevent overlapping objects.

An alternative would also be that the brighter pixels dominate.

How could that be done?

Result:

[image]

The single object:

[image]

My code:

```
(*a single object*)
objectData = GaussianMatrix[20, 0];
object = Image[objectData/Max[objectData]];

(*the test image,here 400 pixels square*)
imageData = Array[0 &, {400, 400}];
image = Image[imageData];

(*some random mean positions*)
randomCoords = Array[{RandomReal[], RandomReal[]} &, 20];

(*image composition*)
ImageCompose[image, object, randomCoords*400]
```

Comment: closely related: [Adding and summing overlapping Airy (or Gaussian) disks on a plane](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/34503/5478)

Comment: `GaussianFilter[RandomImage[BernoulliDistribution[.0002], {300, 300}], 
  10] // ImageAdjust`

Comment: Strictly speaking, since Gaussians don't have compact support, the objects will always be overlapping unless you *truncate* the Gaussians. It might become clearer what the best answer would be if you specify what the desired purpose is.

Comment: The objects should represent simulated spherical micro-particles that are illuminated with a laser plane and recorded perpendicular to the laser plane with a camera. The scattered light from the particles is in the ideal case Gaussian distributed.

Comment: The code shown appears to be riddled with name changes e.g. `image/img`, `object/particle`.

Comment: Sorry I have corrected that ...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Update:**

Belisarius suggested [in comments](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/107702/creation-of-a-test-image-with-2d-circular-shaped-objects-having-gaussian-brightn/107706#comment291321_107702) a method using image processing (i.e. `GaussianFilter`) to generate the image. I'd modify his approach to use `RandomChoice` to generate the initial spots, which seems more direct to me:

```
img = Image@RandomChoice[{10000, 1} -> {0, 1}, {400, 400}];
ImageAdjust@GaussianFilter[img, 15]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

I am going to create your object as the PDF of a binormal distribution with means equal to the $(x,y)$ position of the object, and equal standard deviations (to give a circular particle image) whose values (8) have been chosen to be pleasing with an image size of 400 units (of course, adjust to taste).

```
Clear[object, positions, imagefunction]
SeedRandom[7]

object[px_, py_] = PDF[BinormalDistribution[{px, py}, {8, 8}, 0], {x, y}];
```

Now generate some random positions, apply the object function to generate those objects, then sum all those distribution PDF to obtain a parametric description of a 3D surface:

```
positions = RandomInteger[{1, 400}, {20, 2}];
imagefunction = Plus @@ object @@@ positions;
```

Finally use `DensityPlot` to slice that surface and obtain your image:

```
DensityPlot[imagefunction, {x, 1, 400}, {y, 1, 400},
  PlotPoints -> 150, ColorFunction -> GrayLevel,
  Frame -> None, PlotRange -> All
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

To get an actual image, rather than a `Graphics` object, use e.g. `Rasterize`, `Export` ...:

```
Rasterize[%]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Also for your solution I have the same problem that the intensities of overlapping objects are higher than for a single one. What I would like to have: Intensity(pixel) = Max [ object1Intensity(pixel), object2Intensity(pixel) ]? (see comment to @Dr belisarius)

Answer (score 10):

One way to proceed is to make an image that contains a single white pixel at each desired center point and then to convolve the small particle with the image:

```
particle = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/gi6U1.png"];
randomCoords = Array[{RandomReal[], RandomReal[]} &, 20];
img = Image[Array[0 &, {400, 400}]];
points = ReplacePixelValue[img, randomCoords*400 -> 1];
ImageConvolve[points, particle]
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

`ImageAdjust`won't work well when there are superpositions,

```
SeedRandom[42];
n = 400;
gf[i_Image] := GaussianFilter[i, {n/20, n/80}]
ImageAdjust [ ri= gf@RandomImage[BernoulliDistribution[50/n^2], {n, n}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Use Clip/Rescale instead:

```
resc = Max@ImageData@gf@Image@SparseArray[{n/2, n/2} -> 1, {n, n}];

Image@Clip@Rescale[ImageData@ri, {0, resc}]
(* or, mostly the same but slower*)
ImageApply[Clip@Rescale[#, {0, resc}] &, ri]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Great solution, only one question: why is the brightness of the overlapping objects higher than the rest?

Comment: @mrz In the rescaled code it isn't "higher", what happens is that the maxima are extended (in the non.rescaled code it is, that's why I suggested to rescale)

Comment: When I measure the maxium brightness or histogram of overlapping objects, then their brightness is higher than of non-overlapping objects http://goo.gl/jIy6ND.

Comment: Oh, I see,you're using `ImageData`. Let me check

Comment: @mrz Fixed with `Clip[ ]`

Comment: Thank you very much for you help. Your code is extremely fast and solves my question - therefore I vote for you. Nevertheless I have one small problem left: my feeling is that the intensities of overlapping objects are summed up and then clipped to 1. **Is it possible that for each overlapping pixel the the higher intensity is used instead of the sum:   `Intensity(pixel) = Max [ object1Intensity(pixel), object2Intensity(pixel) ]`?** See also: http://goo.gl/uLpaX9

Comment: @mrz Yes, But it doesn't look nice to me `is = ImageAdjust /@ 
   gf /@ Image /@ (SparseArray[{#} -> 1, {n, n}] & /@ 
       RandomInteger[{1, n}, {50, 2}]);
ImageApply[Max, is]`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a pedestrian way to avoid overlaps. I'll show it "by hand" although it could be automated. I believe this or something similar came up once before on this forum but I cannot seem to locate it.

The original setup is as follows.

```
rad = 20;
scale = 400;
objectData = GaussianMatrix[rad, 0];
object = Image[objectData/Max[objectData]];
imageData = Array[0 &, {scale, scale}];
image = Image[imageData];
SeedRandom[1111];
randomCoords = RandomReal[1, {20, 2}];
image1 = ImageCompose[image, object, randomCoords*scale]
```

[image]

To get something similar but without overlaps we can iteratively use `Nearest`. I'll show one approach although there are others. The idea is to select only points that have no neighbor too close. This is inefficient insofar as we could take one from any pair that overlap, but implementing that means in effect changing the `NearestFunction` in a loop.

```
SeedRandom[1111];
randomCoords = Array[{RandomReal[], RandomReal[]} &, 40];
nf = Nearest[randomCoords];
randomCoords2 = 
  Select[randomCoords, 
   With[{nbr = nf[#, {2, 2/Sqrt[scale]}]}, Length[nbr] == 1] &];
Length[randomCoords2]
randomCoords3 = Array[{RandomReal[], RandomReal[]} &, 30];
nf2 = Nearest[Join[randomCoords2, randomCoords3]];
randomCoords4 = 
  Select[randomCoords3, 
   With[{nbr = nf2[#, {2, 2/Sqrt[scale]}]}, Length[nbr] == 1] &];
Length[randomCoords4]

(* Out[246]= 11

Out[250]= 9 *)
```

We again have 20 points as luck would have it. So let's look at the placement this time.

```
image2 = ImageCompose[image, object, 
  Join[randomCoords2, randomCoords4]*400]
```

[image]